# HQL query to search for mutiple strings in a postgresql database table field

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

I use `postgresql` database and `hibernate` in my `Java Web Application`. I have a table `contents` with `content_data` as a text field. Its corresponding `POJO` is named `ContentTO`and has the following fields with `contentData` for the database field `content_data`:
public class ContentTO

```
{
    private int contentId;
    private String contentData;
    private int applicationId;
    private int siteId;
    private int userCreated;
    private int userModified;
    private Date createdTime;
    private Date updatedTime;
}
```

I have the following method:

```
public List<ContentTO> listContentsBySearchStrings(String searchData, int applicationId, int siteId) throws HibernateException 
    {
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("ContentTO where siteId = :siteId and lower(contentData) LIKE :searchString ");
        query.setParameter("siteId", siteId);
        query.setParameter("applicationId", applicationId);
        query.setParameter("searchString", "%"+searchData+"%");
        List<ContentTO> resultsList = query.list();
        if(resultsList != null && ! resultsList.isEmpty())
        {
            return resultsList;
        }
        return new ArrayList<ContentTO>();
    }
```

This method will work if only a single string is searched in the field. I am trying to search for multiple string which can be comma separated in the parameter passed.

I also tried the following SQL to test the query:

```
SELECT * FROM contents
WHERE content_data LIKE '%mydata'
  AND content_data LIKE '%testdata'
  AND content_data LIKE '%totest';
```

Is there any way to do this using hql when the parameter is a comma separated string .

Comment: **"But this query will return the row even if the content_data contain mydata1234. Is there any way to do this using hql."**

Ofcourse it will return that data because your `WHERE content_data LIKE '%mydata%'` condition matches 1234 for mysql.

Comment: @sumitbadaya, thanks, I have updated the question

Comment: Still unclear. Show a concrete example of two or three rows, and of what your variables contain, and of what the query is supposed to return. But in general, if you're storing comma-separated strings in a column, then don't do that, and use a separate table with a OneToMany or an ElementCollection. And if you have a comma-separated string in your variable, then don't do that either, and pass a List<String> or Set<String> instead.

Comment: Maybe you are wanting to use `OR` not `AND`

Comment: @JBNizet, its not comma separated string in the column, its a text field, it can contain anything, I want search for a string in that text field, so if the search string contains multiple values, it will be passed as comma separated string

Answer (score 0):

you can use "IN" where the parameter is a list of strings in your case:

```
...where content_data in (:listOfYourStrings)
```